# Can I add a lean-to to a large shed?

Tags: code-compliance, shed

Is adding a large lean-to roof for a large shed going to exceed the limits for the IBC definition of a shed?  The shed (details below) is already at the IBC limits for shed area and height.

The lean-to would be along the long edge of the shed and be approximately 33.5 x 12 feet, no higher than 9.5', with a pitch of 2/12 to 3/12.  Posts would support it on the low side.

The shed has a footprint of 28.5 x 14' (399sf).  The eave height is 9.5' (IBC definition of shed as I understand it),  The shed also has 3' overhangs on all sizes and a dual slope roof (7/12 and 10/3) that results in a total height of about 20'.  The projection of the roof is currently 33.5 x 20.

Comment: What's a 10/3 slope?

Comment: You're going to have to contact your local building department, they're the only ones that can answer this question.

Comment: @isherwood That would be a 40/12 slope, I think?

Comment: That's my guess, but why the weird notation? Also, that's church-steeple steep.

Comment: 10" rise over 3" run? Yeek

Comment: 10/3, 40/12 - to me they're just ratios for atan2()....  To keep it a shed, I needed to bring the roof 'eave' back down to <10 feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as I infer) you are in an area where an "IBC Shed" is not requiring a permit, and larger things are, you either need to separate the  new space (so you have two "sheds" that are not actually connected) or you need to pull a permit; unless your area restricts you to one "shed" and then you're simply going to have to pull a permit.

If memory serves, the IBC definition is based on "projected roof area" of the "shed" - so two conjoined maximum-sized  "sheds" are no longer a "shed."

Comment: When I requested the permit, our inspector only cared about the footprint, not the roof projection - so its still a shed in our town.  Any chance you could find the roof projection statement in the 'IBC'?  I guess once I bring support posts down to the ground, I grow the footprint....

Comment: I did not bother to look it up, I'm simply going on what I recalled; could be wrong. As always, the LAHJ interprets as they like. And yes, if the posts hit the ground the footprint gets bigger.